# Azure App Configuration - Replica for 429 HTTP responses

Tags: .net, azure, configuration, sdk

We have a suite of applications, and we want to reuse a single App Configuration (Standard) that can be shared. We have around 20 apps, and did compute I don't envision we'll hit the 30k threshold per hour.

We'll continue monitoring (e.g. if usage goes beyond 70% of the quota, we'll consider spinning up another App Config).

I know replicas are supposed to be used for failovers, or if we have apps coming from the replica's region, to reduce latency. Or if we get errors accessing the primary replica, it would go to the secondary replica to pull app settings/flags.

But in case we experience 429 threshold responses, will the Azure SDK use the replica?

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-geo-replication?tabs=dotnet#scale-and-failover-with-replicas
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/faq#my-application-receives-http-status-code-429-responses--why